# Custom Tab / Visualforce / App To Filter Multiple Fields / Columns?

Tags: visualforce, reporting, appexchange, filters, customization

I desire to have a flat single table/object of data, where we will **filter, field by field, until we end up with one record.**

**Think:**  Inventory (see the screenshots from Excel).

**In Excel:**  I'm talking about Auto-Filtering.

I could not find anything canned in AppExchange.  **Does anyone know of any already-available options to do this?**  *I don't want to redevelop the wheel, so to speak.*

**The complete table...**
[image: The complete table]

**...after filtering down to one row/record**
[image: After filtering down to one record]

So here, you'd select options from each Field (either left to right, or whatever order you like, maybe starting with Interface) until you end up with the one you want.  Your SKU (in this case) is shown on the left.

*If there were only a way to grab the functionality of the filter-builder from the Report Editor and throw it at a specific object with a Picklist for each Field onscreen...*

Comment: I think you're going to have to roll your own here.

Comment: You might look at something like [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) which does all the heavy lifting for you, but you'll still have to do some custom coding.